# Evaluate a string of parameters

Tags: php, csv, array-multisort

I am attempting to create a multisort functionality using an array created from a parsed CSV file.

Here is an example output of what this array looks like

```
Array (
[1] => Array
    (
        [attribute_set] => Area Rug
        [baybin] => 19B
        [refnumber] => 
        [sku] => 3K34302300
        [rug_size] => 5 x 8
        [collection] => Suncoast
        [style] => Brooke
        [stylenumber] => 3K343
        [colorname] => Sage
        [colornumber] => 02300
        [weight] => 15.0000
        [sold_on] => Overstock
        [shape] => Rectangle
        [yarn] => Olefin
        [construction] => Woven
        [qty] => 58.0000
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [attribute_set] => Area Rug
        [baybin] => 33C
        [refnumber] => 746916
        [sku] => 3K46500100
        [rug_size] => 5 x 8
        [collection] => Grace Bay
        [style] => Beige
        [stylenumber] => 3K465
        [colorname] => Beige/natural
        [colornumber] => 00100
        [weight] => 27.0000
        [sold_on] => Amazon
        [shape] => Rectangle
        [yarn] => 
        [construction] => Woven
        [qty] => 0.0000
    )
```

### My initial idea

I would be sending the sort and filter parameters through $_GET.
The format would look something like

> products.php?C:Suncoast,s:,Z:8 x 10

Using that format, I would first multisort the entire contents of the array created from the CSV, shown below.

For instance, a captial `C` would stand for Collection Descending, small `s` for Size Ascending.
The colon after the letter indicates the value I would filter by.. **AFTER** the array is sorted.

My goal is to have these sorts combined; just like in SQL where you can ORDER BY several columns.

So, the only solution I came up with was to create a dynamic string by looping through the parsed GET variables and creating a single string that I would call like so

```
eval("array_multisort($evalstring);");
```

As far as I know, `array_multisort` can only be called one time if I expect a multiple sort functionality i.e sort by collection first, then that by qty.

### Perhaps?

Perhaps I am going about this all wrong?  Is there a better way to accomplish this?  It's usage would be for sorting products (as well as filtering them) to narrow the list down.

Comment: You say "s" for "size ascending", but the given data only has "rug_size" .. is that the same thing?

Comment: Also, `s` would be `Shape Ascending`.  `z` is size (rug_size)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php#68450 seems to be a potential solution, but it is 8 years old.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would create some convenience functions that help to build the parts that go into `array_multisort()`:

```
function getColumn($array, $descriptor)
{
    switch ($descriptor) {
        case 'C': case 'c':
            $name = 'collection';
            break;

        case 'S': case 's':
            $name = 'shape';
            break;

        default:
            // use your imagination
    }

    return array_column($array, $name);
}

function getDirection($descriptor)
{
    return strpos('CS', $descriptor) === false ? SORT_ASC : SORT_DESC;
}
```

Then build the arguments:

```
$sortParameters = array(&$data);
// based on whatever parses the sorting descriptor
if (false) {
    $sortParameters[] = getColumn($data, 'C');
    $sortParameters[] = getDirection('C');
}
```

And finally call the sort function:

```
call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $sortParameters);
```

#### Parsing

Here's an idea for a parsing routine:

```
$str = 'C:Suncoast,s:,Z:8 x 10';
parse_str(strtr($str, ':,', '=&'), $descriptors);

foreach ($descriptors as $symbol => $filter_value) {
    // etc. etc.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going to try an implement this solution.

Comment: I understand the use of strpos in get Direction, but what if the letter is both lowercase and NOT one of the options?  For instance, `x` would not be in the list.

Comment: @dockeryZ you would first have to make sure the character is valid

Answer (score 0):

## I Gave Into MySQL

Traversing that CSV file was like trying to pick a lock with a an old rusty paperclip; it might work once, but it's not exactly scalable.  The entire time that I attempted and failed and attempted again to make it work, I was eager to finish the project quickly.  Using a database was my easy way out of this one.

I simply converted my CSV to a MySQL table and creating the dynamic `ORDER BY`s and `WHERE` was much easier.

Now I'm on a role.